# Run `rustc` to check a program without generating any files

Tags: rust

As `cargo check` shows, it's often useful to check if your program is well-formed without actually generating code (an often pretty time-consuming task). I want to check a single (library) Rust file with `rustc` directly (I cannot use Cargo!).

`cargo check` apparently works by calling this:

```
rustc --emit=metadata -Z no-codegen
```

This only emits metadata, a `.rmeta` file. Cargo actually needs that to check crates dependent on the checked crate. In my case I really don't need the metadata file.

I tried the following:

```
rustc --crate-type=lib --emit=
rustc --crate-type=lib --emit=nothing
```

But both didn't work. I use `--crate-type=lib` because my file doesn't have a `main` function. I need a platform-independent solution (I don't just want to use it on my machine, but use it in a public script).

**How do I make `rustc` not write a single file?**

Answer (score 5):

You can just skip the `--emit` flag.

The final command would then be: `rustc -Z no-codegen rust.rs`

Comment: This is only suitable on the nightly compiler.

Comment: Oh interesting did not even consider that this might be nightly only.

Comment: @H2O Thanks and sorry for my slow reply! Sadly, that doesn't help me for a strange reason: it doesn't work with `--crate-type=lib`. But my file doesn't have a `main` function, so I need `--crate-type=lib`, right? I also updated the question. (edit: nightly only answers are fine!)

Comment: Why doesn't `rustc -Z no-codegen rust.rs` still not work on Rust stable when it works on nightly?

Answer (score 5):

To quote [my own GitHub comment](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1497#issuecomment-414275379) about this very question, there are a few options for stable Rust:

- `rustc --emit=mir -o /dev/null` seems to work in 1.18 and newer, writing nothing. (`--emit=mir` is the only helpful `--emit` option—the others try to create silly files like `/dev/null.foo0.rcgu.o`, except `--emit=dep-info`, which does no checking.)
- `rustc -C extra-filename=-tmp -C linker=true` (i.e. use `/bin/true` as a “linker”) seems to work in all versions, writing some intermediate files but cleaning them up.
- `rustc --out-dir=<new empty temporary directory>` is less clever and therefore perhaps less likely to break?

Note that linker errors, if any, will not be found by the first two options (nor by the nightly-only `-Zno-codegen` option).

Comment: The closest I've found to a ticket tracking clean addition of this functionality is https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52661. Should there also be a tracking ticket for the existing `-Z no-codegen` nightly feature somewhere?