# Does Rust have a way to perform syntax and semantic analysis without generating code?

Tags: rust, typechecking

Compilers such as gcc, clang and gccgo all have the switch `-fsyntax-only` used in single-buffer syntax checkers such as Flycheck. These only perform syntactic and, I assume, semantic analysis, thereby skipping code generation. Does Rust have something similar?

Comment: Related: [Run `rustc` to check a program without generating any files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51485765/155423)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cargo check` command instructs `cargo` to do just that.

It will check the syntax, types and borrows without generating any code.

Comment: "without generating _any_ code" - I think that cargo still must compile and run `build.rs` scripts.

Comment: @ozkriff: True, "code" here does not mean "source code". I am not sure how to improve the wording, though.

Comment: Additionally, `cargo check` has the benefit of being slightly quicker that a full build, so it makes sense to use primarily when developing.